# How to Fix SSMS 19 Preview 2 failing to connect to Azure DB

Tags: azure, ssms

I've been using **SSMS 18** for ages, np, apart from the occasionally random freeze/crash.

I saw **SSMS 19 Preview 2** was available so installed it along side 18.

On trying to login to my usual **Azure DB**s, using exactly the same details as I do in 18, I get the following error:

```
Cannot connection to XXX.database.windows.net / The operation was cancelled (mscorlib)
```

Has anyone else tried to use SSMS 19 with Azure DBs and encountered the same issue?

Comment: [Known issues SSMS 19.0 Preview 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms-19?view=sql-server-ver16#known-issues-190-preview-2)

Comment: Still can't logon to Preview 3, with no indication as to why...  Will do some more digging!